# Constraining a Variable Within a Set using Opti Toolbox and NOMAD in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am using the Opti Toolbox and the NOMAD blackbox optimizer to optimize some integer parameters. Right now, the optimizer is chosing the integer value of the parameters given a lower and upper bound. I want the optimizer to constrain the value to a value given in a certain set i.e x should be either 1000, 1500, 2000 or 2500 with 1000 and 2500 being the lower resp. upper bound. I need some help on how I would define this set using NOMAD and the Opti Toolbox in MATLAB.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let the solver pick an integer value `k` between 1 and 4, and use:

```
a = [1000 1500 2000 2500]
x = a(k)
```

in your objective function.